# Different captions for float and non float figures

Tags: captions

I use following code for nonfloat figures..

```
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=3.0in]{myimage.eps}
    \captionof{figure}{Caption for image}
    \label{fig:sample_figure}
\end{minipage}
```

I want caption as

> Caption for image

and for float figures

```
   \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=3.0in]{myimage.eps}
    \caption{Caption for image}
    \label{fig:sample_figure2}
   \end{figure}
```

Here i want caption as

> Figure 1.1 Caption for image

How to achieve this?

Comment: Instead of using `captionof{figure}` you can define a new float-environment with your request style definition and then using `captionof` with this new environment name. So the counter is independently. BTW: A small MWE is useful.

Comment: Do you not want to count the non-floats? (It seems so from your example.) If so, can't you just *not* use `\captionof` at all, but write the caption directly?

Comment: yes I do not want to count non-floats

Comment: @sandu: Do you want an entry in the list of figures?

Answer (score 2):

To get an unnumbered caption you can use the starred version of the command `\captionof`. Please note that the starred version doesn't provide an entry in the list of ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\section{foo}
\blindtext

\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=3.0in]{example-image-a}
    \captionof*{figure}{Caption for image}
    \label{fig:sample_figure}
\end{minipage}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=3.0in]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Caption for image}
    \label{fig:sample_figure2}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```